# Catching errors from functions in arguments for another function

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with some basic error handling/catching. If I have the following code:

```
function test() {
    areThereErrors(sum(1,2));
    areThereErrors(sumo(1,2));
}

function areThereErrors(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

How do I go about catching the error from the typo in the second call to areThereErrors? My basic understanding is that I have to call test() but unfortunately I only console.log 3 once and that's it. I want to be able to return true if sumo throws an error because sumo isn't a function.

NOTE: The crux of the issue is, is it possible to catch the error with code WITHIN areThereErrors?

Comment: The problem is that `sumo` won't throw an error because it is not a function and thus never called. Instead, `test()` will throw the error so that's also the location in which you'd need to catch the error

Comment: Take a look at `try` and `catch`.

Comment: @burnedikt `sumo` will indeed throw an error (a ReferenceError) when the attempt is made to call it.

Comment: I have used try and catch plenty of times. My issue comes in that the error seems to get thrown when you invoke `test` rather than when you invoke `areThereErrors(sumo(1,2))`

Comment: There is no reason calling `test()` would throw an error. You yourself said that you saw the console log from the call to `areThereErrors(sum(1,2))`, proving that `test` was called and started to execute until the error in the following line.

Comment: `sumo(1,2)` is executed before passing its returned value into `areThereErrors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The crux of the issue is, is it possible to catch the error with code WITHIN `areThereErrors`?

No, because the error will be thrown when the parameters to `areThereErrors` are evaluated in preparation to calling it, and it will never be called.

However, you could make `areThereErrors` work in the way you seem to want to by passing it a **function** to be executed.

```
function areThereErrors(fn) {
  try { console.log(fn()); }
  catch (e) { console.log("Oh, no, an error has been thrown"); return true; }
}
```

Now you can write your code as

```
function test() {
    areThereErrors(() => sum(1,2)));
    areThereErrors(() => sumo(1,2)));
}
```

Another alternative is to make `areThereErrors` into a higher-order function which takes one function as input and returns another function which wraps a call to it in try/catch. The approach would be:

```
function areThereErrors(fn) {
  return function() {
    try {
      return fn(...arguments);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  };
}
```

Now you can write code such as

```
function test() {
    areThereErrors(sum)(1, 2);
    areThereErrors(sumo)(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: I know that would work, I am trying to understand if there is a way to catch the error within the areThereErrors function rather that in the invoking of the test function.

Comment: No, there is not. Before `areThereErrors` is called, its parameters are evaluated, which in this case involves the call to the non-existent `sumo`, so execution stops before `areThereErrors` has a chance to be called. There is a reason `try/catch` is a language construct rather than a library call.

Comment: If sumo was a function that intentionally threw an error would `areThereErrors` be able to catch that?

Comment: @chasenyc Yes, it would because any error that occurs in the try is caught. No matter how deep. But, see my answer for reasons why try/catch should be used sparingly.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks, I guess the crux of my issue was not understanding that parameters are evaluated before the function itself. Thanks for the prompt responses!

Comment: The order of execution is that `sumo(1, 2)` is called first, in order to derive the value to pass as a parameter to `areThereErrors`. If `sumo(1, 2)` throws for any reason, whether it be due to the fact that `sumo` does not exist, or `sumo` exists but throws an error, execution stops at that moment (unless a try/catch is in effect). Once `sumo(1,2)` successfully executes, and produces a value, **and only then**, is `areThereErrors` called with that value. So no, `areThereErrors` **cannot** detect or do anything about an error which was thrown, for whatever reason, before it was even called.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand that not all errors are run-time errors that can be caught. A syntax error (like missing a bracket) will prevent the code from running in the first place.

Next, if you have code that may encounter run-time errors, you have two options:

1. **Use Try/Catch** (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch for more)

   ```
   try{
       // some code to "try" to execute
   } catch (ex) {
       // programmatic flow is passed here if code in try causes exception
       // Actual exception object can be accessed through catch argument (ex in this case)

   } finally {
       // Regardless of whether the try code succeeded or not, the finally will always be executed.

   }
   ```

> WARNING: This is often misused by developers as a way to catch errors
>   that should not have come up in the first place, but do because the
>   developer didn't write robust enough code. Also, be aware that
>   exception objects have catch block scope, as such there are performance
>   implications to using try/catch as well as it leading to poor code quality.

2. **Set up error event handler**

> The window object provides a "hook" into an error event. Since most
>   events "bubble" up to the window object. An event handler for window's
>   error event can provide a catch all type of routine. But, there is no
>   standard for implementing this technique as of yet and different
>   clients use different code:

```
    // AddEventListener will pass the error object to your callback:
    window.addEventListener("error", function (evt) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + evt.message);
      console.log("\tURL: " + evt.filename);
      console.log("\tLine: " + evt.lineno);
      console.log("\tColumn: " + evt.colno);
      // The error "may" still be presented to user
    }, false);

    // Chrome & Opera pass error details and the error object
    // (new standard) via .onerror
    window.onerror = function (message, file, line, col, error) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + message);
      console.log("\tURL: " + file);
      console.log("\tLine: " + line);
      console.log("\tColumn: " + col);
      console.log("\tObject: " + error);
      return true;  // Indicate that error has been handled
    };
```